# Where is the documentation for Node.js gRPC API?

Tags: node.js, grpc-node

Currently https://grpc.io/docs/reference/ points at https://grpc.io/grpc/node/, where the "API Documentation" link just points to itself.

Is there an official API reference? (Googling for methods with names like `.on` or `.cancel` is not very productive.)

Comment: No, this is not a question _"asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam"._ This is a question about canonical _official_ documentation; an answer can't be very opinionated.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are there, but have usability issue.

To actually see the API docs, one needs to use the top menu.
The link in the "API Documentation" section is poor usability, though.